# String [] to String

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text file and i want to read each word into an `ArrayList<Dictionary>` but I have to leave commas, dashes, dots etc. This is the code so far for this purpose:

```
Scanner sc2 = null;    
while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
    while (s2.hasNext()) {
        String s = s2.next();
        String[] tokens = s.split("\\W+");
        s  = tokens.toString();
        Dictionary.add(s);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I execute the printing code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Dictionary.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(Dictionary.get(i));
}
```

I get the following:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@ea2f77
[Ljava.lang.String;@ea6137
[Ljava.lang.String;@ea639
```

Etc. for every word. I belive that the problem is `s = tokens.toString();` but i do not know how to fix it. 
Thank you!

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention that for some reason, eclipse does not let me use `Arrays.` . Everytime i try to use it, importing the library i get errors.

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;` this is the import statement.

Comment: Yes i imported but got errors. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Also note that it looks to me like you could get rid of the split statement and the second scanner by simply iterating over sc2.hasNext() and adding each word to the dictionary.

Comment: @Maria maybe your eclipse do not have whole source of java :P

Comment: I tried a lot of things nothing worked though! May i ask, how to i check the "whole source of java"?

Comment: It seems that every time i use `collections.` i get the same error `The type java.util.comparator cannot be resolved`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tokens` is an array of `Strings`, and as such its `toString()` method returns what you see in your output. You need to iterate over each `String` in `tokens` and add them to the `Dictionary` individually, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    Dictionary.add(tokens[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Maria - great! If that's the case, you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark over there <---

Comment: Yep! Gonna do it in 5 minutes(when it allows me to)

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to avoid for loops; then just use `java.util.Arrays`--

```
s = Arrays.toString(s.split("\\W+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that has already been asked, but here's the answer:

```
String punctutations = ".,:;";//add all the ones you want.
if(punctutations.contains(letter[a])) //If the character at letter[a] contains a punctuation mark
```